# Finding Characters in vb.net string

Tags: vb.net, foreach, substring, indexof

I have a stack overflow question regarding the following code:

```
For Each DeltaCharB As Char In DeltaString
    If DeltaCharB = "[" Then
        Dim DeltaIndexB As Integer = TB8.IndexOf("[B|")
        Dim DeltaStringB As String = TB8.Substring(DeltaIndexB + 3, TB8.IndexOf("]", DeltaIndexB + 1) - DeltaIndexB - 3)
        MsgBox(DeltaStringB)
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If
Next
```

The issue created is that if the code is run X number of times that the character "[" is found, The string is displayed the same X amount of times in a messagebox.

However I only want to have it processed 1X. I have tried to change the following line but as i expected only one character at a time is permitted.

```
If DeltaCharB = "[B|" Then
```

Typically the string used to search in would be as follows:

```
{[A|Text belonging to entry A][B|Text belonging to entry B][C|Text belonging to entry C]}.... ect...ect
```

Dose anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Please think about readability when posting code snippets. Code that is indented six times more than it needs to be is less readable for no good reason. If selecting your code and clicking the CODE button six times is too much trouble, use the `Alt` when selecting your code so you can select an arbitrary block.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you mean that you want to exit the loop after finding a match then that's exactly what you should do. As for determining what substring starts at the current index, you'd have to know what the current index is, which you don't if you're using a `For Each` loop.  Use a `For` loop and then you can call `Substring` to test multiple characters.

Comment: Side note: "`Else        'Do nothing`". Then why bother? Drop the `Else`...

Comment: How about `Exit For` after the `MsgBox`?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a loop? Your delimiters are well defined, you can just do this:

```
Function GetContent(byval input as string, byval delimiter as string) as string
    Dim fullDelimiter = "["& delimiter &"|"
    Dim BeginPosition as Integer = input.IndexOf(fullDelimiter)
    if BeginPosition > -1 then
        BeginPosition += fullDelimiter.Length
        Dim EndPosition = input.IndexOf("][", BeginPosition)
        if EndPosition > -1 then
            return input.SubString(BeginPosition, EndPosition - BeginPosition)
        end if
    end if
    return ""
End Function
```

And the usage:

```
Dim s as string = "[A|Text belonging to entry A][B|Text belonging to entry B][C|Text belonging to entry C]"

Dim content = GetContent(s, "B")
```

content now contains "Text belonging to entry B"

Note that with this code, the delimiter can by a string of any length between `[` and `|`.

A more general solution that will fit any input format would mean to also accept the end delimiter in the function:

```
Function GetContent(byval input as string, byval FromDelimiter as string, byval ToDelimiter as string) as string
    Dim BeginPosition as Integer = input.IndexOf(FromDelimiter)
    if BeginPosition > -1 then
        BeginPosition += FromDelimiter.Length
        Dim EndPosition = input.IndexOf(ToDelimiter, BeginPosition)
        if EndPosition > -1 then
            return input.SubString(BeginPosition, EndPosition - BeginPosition)
        end if
    end if
    return ""
End Function
```

Comment: Probably you should add the delimiter also to find the end of the substring. Otherwise any stray ] inside the block of text will be used to clip the returned value. Of course this will require a recalculation of the length for the chars to extract in the substring

Comment: @Steve while your comment is correct, I think for this specific input format it's enough to just use `][` as the end delimiter. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Steve on second thought, I've also included the more general function.